# Docker Remote Development Server

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code, containers, virtual-machine

I wonder if I could set up a remote development server using Docker. Until now I was using VSCode with the Remote SSH extension to connect to my server(Debian) and work on my projects. But now I would like to set up an environment, where I can have more developers connected at the same time, each working on their own projects. From my understanding Docker creates something like a lightweight VM(container). So I guess it would be perfect if all of them could have their own Docker container with their own terminal and files.

So my questions are:
-Is it possible to set up something like that?
-How should I set up the whole thing?
-Does Docker have any kind of authentication so the developers could connect remotely to the server with an username and password or something like that?
-If not, can I do the same SSH thing like before, but separate the users into these containers? So the users will SSH into the container not the VM?

I'm really new into Docker so I would appreciate all you help and suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: I think you find this one https://github.com/cdr/code-server

Comment: If you are open to suggestions, my advice to you is to avoid remote development servers. Setting up local development environments is easier and has more advantages. If your app is too complex, use docker locally as well.

Comment: Docker has _no_ authentication, and anyone who can run any Docker command at all can trivially root the host.  The setup you describe isn't impossible (it isn't too dissimilar from what [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) does, for example) but it's probably not what I'd reach for as my first Docker project.